# Form into a form with Tizen

Tags: layout, tizen, tizen-native-app

I started using Tizen SDK to develop a native app. And I have to make a form into a form. Actually, it works, but I've some bugs with it. I mean, the footer bar is bugged, when I click on an item from the footer. The app crash immediatly...

Do you know how to resolve it ?
Thanks

Comment: Where in the code does it crash (have you checked the call stack in the Tizen IDE)? What does that code look like?

Comment: Please post minimal code sample that reproduces the problem. As for me it looks like you didn't handle some errors that occured during your form initialization

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it a good choice to make a Form into a Form. If you want reuse UI form, it's better to use **Panel** instead.

Here is description of Panel from dev guide.
Tizen::Ui::Controls::Panel class is a general rectangular container that you can use to group UI controls, or even other panels. Panels can be used to create a custom background for a defined area, or for organizing and aligning UI controls. However, by default, the look-and-feel of a panel does not differ from its surrounding Tizen::Ui::Controls::Form control.